# Inverse trignometry ineqality.

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inequality, inverse-function

The question is -

$$sin^{-1}(x)>cos^{-1}x   ∨\  x\ ∃ (0,1)$$

I am getting two different answers by two different methods.I know which method is wrong and which one is right, as i plotted the solution of this inequality on Desmos. I am only posting the wrong solution and wish to find out what's wrong in my method.

$$sin^{-1}(x)+cos^{-1}(x) = \frac {\pi}{2}  $$

Substituting $$sin^{-1}(x)= - cos^{-1}(x) + \frac {\pi}{2}  $$

and if we substitute this in the original question we get

$$  2cos^{-1}(x) < \frac {\pi}{2}  $$

or $$  cos^{-1}(x) < \frac {\pi}{4}  $$

taking  cos and we get    $$  x <cos( \frac {\pi}{4} ) $$

and get the solution $$ x \ ∃\  (0,\frac{1}{\sqrt2})  $$

If i replace $$ cos^{-1}(x)\ with\ sin^{-1}(x)$$ then i am getting $$ x \ ∃\  (\frac{1}{\sqrt2},1)  
$$

which apparently  is the correct answer.  At which step i am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because $\cos$ decreases.

I think, it's better to use another way.

We need $$x>\sin\arccos{x}$$ or
$$x>\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ or
$$x>\frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$$